# Doctrine ORM Zendframework 2 вывод все даные из таблицу

Tags: php, doctrine2, zend-framework-2

Как можно выводить все данные (fetchAll) из таблицу в Doctrine ORM Zendframework 2.5

Comment: `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::findAll()` не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала нужно получить EntityManager, напр. заинжектить в класс через фабрику.
Затем в контроллере ловите его в конструкторе:

```
private $entityManager;


public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

Далее в Экшенах через него делаете выборку.

```
$categories = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Category::class)->findAll();
```

Можете сделать свои репозитории, и поиск будет происходить учитывая Ваши условия.